# Cómo almacenar html en javascript que no sea en una variable

Tags: javascript

Tengo varias lineas de *html* que necesito mantener en *javascript* para luego ser invocadas pero la única manera que he encontrado es almacenando en una *variable* cosa que se me hace un poco fastidioso ya que todo está amontonado y no puedo trabajar bien, que otra manera puedo usar?

```
var set = ".<div id='01'>contenido</div>etc..."
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Puedes poner el html en el documento con la etiqueta `<template>`, el html dentro de `<template>` no se renderiza, luego, cuando lo necesites, puedes extraer ese html con javascript y manipularlo.

```
<template id="codigoPlantilla">
      <h2>Flower</h2>
      <img src="img_white_flower.jpg">
</template>
```

Otra forma, si usas una versión reciente de JS sería colocar el texto entre ``, así lo puedes mantener formateado:

```js
var html = `
  <html>
    <body></body>
  </html>
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes guardar varias lineas de código en una sola variable concatenando con JS

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var data="";
      data="<table border='1'>"+
          "<tr>"+
             "<td> head 1 </td>"+
             "<td> head 2 </td>"+
           "</tr>"+
           "<tr>"+
             "<td> text 1 </td>"+
             "<td> text 2 </td>"+
           "</tr>"+
          "</table>";

$("#tabla").append(data);   

});
</script>
```

en tu .html

```
<div id="tabla">
</div>
```

Comment: Aunque sigue siendo el mismo punto de mucho código en una sola variable que es lo que ya tiene el no?

Comment: lo que entendí es que esta guardando todo el código html en una sola linea y al hacerse de esa forma se dificulta identificar donde abren y cierras los divs.